# MongoDB smallfiles configuration

Tags: mongodb

We are having a replica set in the production on MongoDB 2.0. Our application creates lots of databases in the system due to that lots of disk space is being utilized. We want to have the smallfiles configuration enabled to minimize the disk usage. What would be the impact of doing it in running replica system? How would old files would be treated in this case? Is there any possibility of data lose?

Comment: A couple of Q's first, which version of MongoDB are you using ? The --smallfiles option favours where you have many DBs with a small amount of data in each but at a cost of performance is you end up with some of the DBs having more data, can you give some size indications here ? What size and makeup is your replica set ? A rolling procedure would address the last two questions but again this depends on the configuration of your replica set.

Comment: We are on mongodb 2.0 and most of the dbs are having less data may be less than 1 GB. Replica set is having 2 nodes and one arbitrary  node.

Comment: This sounds like it might be related to the schema design, you could potentially use fewer DBs and more collections to achieve the same effect with rearchitecting the DB schema. Have you considered this approach instead ?

Comment: You will find better space usage by upgrading to 2.4 and using power of 2 sizes at a DB level but I would also suggest a review of your schema as well. The path from 2.0 is to upgrade to 2.2 (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.2/#upgrading-a-replica-set) then upgrade from 2.2 to 2.4 (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4-upgrade/#upgrade-a-replica-set-from-mongodb-2-2-to-mongodb-2-4) in a rolling fashion.